# Inequality - Maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials, maximum-principle

***Exercise :***

Let :

$$p(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kz^k$$

a polynomial of degree $n$.

If :$$|p(z)|\leq M ,\forall |z|<1$$ show that :

$$|p(z)| \leq M|z|^n, \forall|z|\geq 1$$

***Attempt :***

Let :

$$q(ζ) := ζ^np\bigg(\frac{1}{ζ} \bigg), |ζ| \leq 1$$

Then :

$$z:=\frac{1}{ζ}$$

which means :

$$q\bigg(\frac{1}{z}\bigg) = \bigg(\frac{1}{z}\bigg)^np(z), |z|\geq1$$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$q\bigg(\frac{1}{z}\bigg) = z^{-n}p(z), |z|\geq1$$

But after here I cannot see how to use the given inequality, that $|p(z)|\leq M ,\forall |z|\leq1$, since we have $|z|\geq 1$.

First of all, I would like to ask if the $|z| \geq 1$ that is being asked is wrong.

Secondly, if it isn't wrong, I would really appreciate any thorough help/solution or tip to continue on with solving it, because it's a part of my collection of exercises for the preparation of the semester exams.

Thanks a lot for your time !

Kind regards,

Charalampos Filippatos, NTUA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are on to something: $q(z)$ is also a polynomial. It
satisfies $|q(z)|\le M$ on the boundary of the unit disc, so also inside
it. Thus if $|z|>1$, $|q(1/z)|\le M$ and so $|p(z)|\le M|z|^n$.